# How to stop Rhythmbox adding played sound files to the library?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

Everytime I play an audio files with Rhythmbox the program adds it to the library automatically. Also when the file stops playing Rhythmbox plays the next file of the library list.

How can I stop this behaviour? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an automatic feature so it's not really possible to not let it be added to the library. What I have done is that I set the default program for music to Totem. That way if I open a music file in Nautilus it opens and plays that file and nothing else. Not ideal but it works for me.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'd completely forgotten about Totem. It can also handle simple playlists which is useful.